# Find the function $f$, given that $ f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x))$ and that $f(0) = \frac12$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Find the function $f$, given that $$f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x))$$ and that $f(0) = \frac12$

The answer is

$$y = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

What I tried doing is changing $f'(x)$ as \frac{dy}{dx} and all the $f(x)$ as $y$ to make it easier to read for myself. Manipulating the equation.

I got

$$\left(y + \frac1y\right)dy = 1dx$$

but when I integrate I'm not getting the correct answer, I'm pretty sure I'm doing this incorrectly. Any advice?

Comment: When you separate, do you not get $\frac {dy}{y(1-y)}=dx$?

Comment: I am not, that's probably where I'm misunderstanding something,....AND it just clicked. If you divide the entire right side by y(1-y) it does not become 0, it becomes 1, so you can transfer dx over to that side.  

For some reason i was doing my right side = 0 and then dx(0)= 0  So i had no dx to integrate. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1-y)$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y(1-y)}=\int dx$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y}+\int\frac{dy}{1-y}=\int dx$$
$$\ln y-\ln(1-y)=x+c$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)=x+c$$
$$f(0)=\frac12$$
Thus, $c=0$.
$$\frac{y}{1-y}=e^{x}$$
$$y=e^{x+c}-ye^{x}$$
$$y(1+e^{x+c})=e^{x}$$
$$y(1+e^{-x})=1$$
$$y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Can you explain how you went from your second to third step?

How did y(1-y) become y + (1-y)

Comment: $\frac1y+\frac1{1-y}=\frac{1-y+y}{y(1-y)}=\frac{1}{y(1-y)}$

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the right hand side you'll obtain the differential equation:
$y'-y= -y^2$ In that equation we let $u=y^{-1}$ so $u'=-y^{-2}y'$ 
Now we multiply the original equation with $-y^-{2}$. 
We now have the equation:
$-y^{-2}y'+y^-{1}=1$ which by our substitution transforms into:
$u'+u=1$ I guess you can take it from here!

Comment: Can you explain how you know to set u  as (y^-1) I've never substituted with something that was not in my equation before.

Comment: These are known as Bernoulli differential equations which are solved by this particular substitution!